# How to make imports in Python

Tags: python, import

my problem is following, I have an application in the following hierarchy:

```
main.py
  package/__init__.py
  package/MyClass.py
```

Clearly there is a package named "package". In the MyClass.py there is a class definition.

Now, while im in "main.py" file, to get the class instance i have to do:

```
package.MyClass.MyClass()
```

in order to create and instance of that class.

Now I want to be able to write only

```
package.MyClass()
```

To instantiate a class. How do I do this? I saw many apis do it this way, is there some trick to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in `__init__.py`:

```
from .MyClass import Myclass
```

Then, in `main.py`:

```
import package
package.MyClass()
```

Or again:

```
from package import MyClass
MyClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `__init__.py`:

```
from .package import MyClass
```

Comment: Where to make that \_\_init\_\_.py?

Comment: It doesnt work, I get error: No module named package